# List View eliminate white color top and bot

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i have a problem with the list view, i see a white transparence when you scroll up or down in the list view and i want to eliminate it

[image: http://subefotos.com/ver/?e24cbda67e3fd394c71afe3c4ca76137o.png]

there is a screen of the app  in a Samsung Galaxy Ace

this is the code of the list view

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pages_tab_rel" >

    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

inside your `<ListView>` xml.

Comment: Are you sure you put this line in all your listviews? because I guess you may have more than one listview.

Answer (score 3):

> *use android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" in listview
>
> *

Comment: getListView().setCacheColorHint(0); in your class

Answer (score 1):

android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"

set cacheColorHint to transparent color

Comment: This looks more like a OEM customization of the listview.Which handset are you testing on? Does this happen on emulator also?